# Getting an empty Python geodataframe while I perform spatial join operation on - polyline/line and points

Tags: python, geopandas, attribute-joins, geodataframe

```
import os
os.environ['USE_PYGEOS'] = '0'
import geopandas as gpd
sv=gpd.read_file(r"D:\Sampledata\Kerala\Schools.shp")
sr=gpd.read_file(r"D:\Map\Kerala\Road_line.shp")
gh=gpd.sjoin(sr, sv, how='inner', predicate='intersects')

gpd.overlay(sr,sv, how='intersection')
```

Coordinate reference system for both the shapefiles are same. I tried to perform spatial join using ArcPy and its working perfectly.
.sni

[image]

Comment: Does my answer work?